# I am installing Nbd cluster in my system

Tags: mysql, cluster

I run this command:-

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.11-debian7-x86_64.deb
```

And i got error:-

```
dpkg: error processing archive mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.11-debian7-x86_64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.11-debian7-x86_64.deb
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Is the file `mysql-cluster-gpl-7.4.11-debian7-x86_64.deb` located in the current directory? If not, supply the full path to `dpkg`.

Comment: I'm going to guess you went to the mysql download site and downloaded the file, `mysql-cluster-gpl-7.5.4-debian7-x86_64.deb` but then copy and pasted the command from a how-to site, which has an outdated version number in the filename.  Run the command again, but by using the file you downloaded.